# chrome.notifications.create() is giving the wrong id when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, settimeout

First post here. This is an issue I've been facing for some times about a personnal project. I once found a similar topic here but I couldn't find it anymore and AFAIR the question wasn't answered.
I must admit that my title is a bit weird but I couldn't find a better way to explain it. Anyway let's go.

I've got this function :
*(url and time are properly given, this is not the issue)*

```js
function setTimer(url, time) {
    var timeHR = time / 1000 / 60;
    idTimerString = saveTimer(url, timeHR);
    console.log(idTimerString);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var options = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "Remind me later !",
            message: ('You asked me to remind you :\n' + url + ' \n' + timeHR + ' minutes ago. Click to open it !'),
            iconUrl: 'img/icon.png'
        }
        chrome.notifications.create(idTimerString, options, function(cb) {
            console.log(cb);
        });
    }, time);

}
```

When this function is called **once** there is no problem, after the delay it is displayed correctly. If I create one call with 30mn (id = 1) and another one juste after with 60mn (id = 2) when I click the first notification I will receive the id 2 and same for the 2nd notification.
But I should have had id 1 then id 2 ! Do you have any idea why ?

*My extension is already online of you want to test the bug but I think it would be considered advertising.*

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it?

Comment: When is setTimer being called? You are aware that idTimerString has a bigger scope than just that function? If they're being created at the same time then the value of idTimerString will have changed by the time the timeout function hits...

Comment: I agree that this is most probably a closure issue. The value of `idTimerString` will be `2` at the time the timeout for the first notification is reached. Try to add `var` before `idTimerString` inside the function. This will make idTimerString local and avoid such dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a closure scope issue. Try to make `idTimerString` local to the function

```
var idTimerString = saveTimer(url, timeHR);
```

Comment: It seems like it solved the problem, I'm getting the good idea and it opens the good page (and one instance of it) !  
I'm doing some more research and I'll mark your answer as accepted, thanks !